# how to capture system.windows.forms.keys when "." key is pressed

Tags: c#, .net

thanks to Hans! this is the trick below

```
this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(TabbedTextBox_KeyPress); 
    void TabbedTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.')
       {
           e.Handled = true;
           var nextControl = this.Parent.GetNextControl(this, forward: true);
           nextControl.Focus();
       }      
    }
```

okay here is a little more detail.

this works but the "." is displayed in the text box control(not desired)

```
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(TabbedTextBox_KeyDown);
    }
    void TabbedTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Event: " + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal || e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
        {               
            var nextControl = this.Parent.GetNextControl(this, forward: true);
            nextControl.Focus();
        }
    }
```

when I use this event handler I cannot bind to e.keycode as it doesnt exist in the context

```
this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(TabbedTextBox_KeyPress);
        void TabbedTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        //MessageBox.Show("KeyPress Event: " + e.KeyChar.ToString());
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Decimal || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemPeriod)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("KeyPress Captured: " + e.KeyChar.ToString());
       }      
    }
```

I am trying to capture when the "." key is pressed as I have created a form that has IP address and I want to auto tab when the "." key is pressed. The first message box displays this message when I press the "." either on the numpad or above the ALT Key, but never enter into the if statement i have tried both

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Decimal)
```

and

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemPeriod)
```

message box shows this
KeyPress Event: .

I just can't seem to figure out what the propper code is....
i have been trying to figure it out from msdn [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xy8ebtbf.aspx)

```
    void TabbedTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("KeyPress Event: " + e.KeyChar.ToString());
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Decimal)
       {
            MessageBox.Show("KeyPress Captured: " + e.KeyChar.ToString());
       }      
    }
```

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 4):

Don't mix up virtual key codes and characters.  In the KeyPress event you get the actual character that was translated from the virtual key by the active keyboard layout.  Thus:

```
        if (e.KeyChar == '.') {
            MessageBox.Show("Period detected");
        }
```

Comment: perfect that works! but how do I not have the period entered into the text box?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `e.KeyChar` try using `e.KeyCode`

Also

```
if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal) || (e.Keyode == Keys.OemPeriod)) {
   //execute tabbing code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be OemPeriod that you're looking for? I beleive the Decimal Key is the . on the numpad.

Comment: Key.Decimal is not the "."; but it is as you said the "," key on the numpad, which write according to the Culture-Info. (it press "." or "," related to the os' language)